# Python regex get match and wait until new match

Tags: python, regex, io

Basically it's an updating log file, so when my function finds the next/latest match it executes another function
But I don't want it to continuously looping and only work when it finds the latest update

is there a way I can pause/wait it until file gets updated and it gets a new match

```
try:
    with open(location, "r") as f:
        for lines in f.readlines():
            for match in re.findall(pattern, lines):
                matches.append(match)
                print(match)
                time.sleep(5)
except Exception:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open()` creates a file-like object which can be iterated over using `readline()`. If you create an infinite loop you will continuously read off the any new lines appended to the file by the other program.

```
with open(location, "r") as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if line: #checks not None
            for match in re.findall(pattern, line)
            matches.append()
            do_work(matches) # call some other function that processes the matches that you have found
```

Comment: Thanks, This Works! But how can I make it like that, it can execute the script when a new match is found?

Comment: Could you explain further? It's an infinite loop so it should never exit. Any new matches will constantly be appended to your matches list. If you need to do something with your matches list you need to call it from within the loop or implement some non-blocking asynchronous code. The difference between my code and yours is that this will only ready the newlines when they are added unlike yours which will start from the beginning of the file and read everything again.

Comment: Ah don't worry about it, I actually managed to get the code working exactly as I wanted :D, So I have no further questions.

Comment: If this answered your question, the mark it as answered and upvote. That way when someone else comes along with a similar question they should already have then answer. Glad you got it sorted.